# zip file made by php shows wrong folder structure in js-dos but correct in windows

Tags: php, zip, dos, dosbox

I am working on a project which requires me to collect several files from the server, zip them, and mount the zip as a drive with js-dos.

Everything works 'correctly'. During testing I manually made a zip file in windows and the code ran. For the final test I tried to mount the php generated zip but the folder structure is strange when doing DIR in js-dos.

I should have a single folder with several files in it. Instead there are several of the same folders with a single file inside.

The thing that breaks my brain is that when I open the file in winRAR it's correct, but in js-dos it's suddenly different.

Here is my code, it's nothing fancy:

```
 $rootPath = realpath($filefoldername."/");
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($filefoldername.'/xp.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

// Create recursive directory iterator
/** @var SplFileInfo[] $files */
$filesZ = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

foreach ($filesZ as $nameZ => $fileZ)
{
    // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
    if (!$fileZ->isDir())
    {
        // Get real and relative path for current file
        $filePath = $fileZ->getRealPath();
        $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);

        // Add current file to archive
        $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
    }
}

// Zip archive will be created only after closing object
$zip->close();
```

I'm guessing that windows over looks something that dos doesn't. zip files made with winRAR are ok, but the ones generated by this code are strange.

I want to generate the .zip in php not by shell command. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ZipArchive::addFile() creates zip files with tree structure in Windows but flattened in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69655014/ziparchiveaddfile-creates-zip-files-with-tree-structure-in-windows-but-flatt)

Comment: it looks right but I'm having trouble adapting it

Comment: i tried this $relativePath = str_replace('\\', '/', $relativePath); but now js-dos doesn't mount the .zip. it looks correct in windows still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe js-dos cannot automatically create intermediate directories, you could try the code below to add intermediate directories to zip file.

```php
$rootPath = realpath($filefoldername."/");
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($filefoldername.'/xp.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

// Create recursive directory iterator
/** @var SplFileInfo[] $files */
$filesZ = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
    // !!!! replace LEAVES_ONLY with SELF_FIRST to include intermediate directories
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);

foreach ($filesZ as $nameZ => $fileZ)
{
    // Get real and relative path for current file
    $filePath = $fileZ->getRealPath();
    $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);
    $relativePath = str_replace('\\', '/', $relativePath);

    if ($fileZ->isDir()) {
        $zip->addEmptyDir($relativePath);
    } else {
        $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
    }
}

// Zip archive will be created only after closing object
$zip->close();
```

Comment: that did the trick, thank you so much! knowing about this will be helpful in the future too